# From Problem Solving Strategies

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, intuition, invariance

I am studying the following example.

[image]

Can someone please explain how the following inequality occurs?

[image]

Comment: is $y_n\leq 0$?

Comment: note that $x_n-y_n<x_n+y_n$ then $\frac{x_n-y_n}{x_n+y_n}<1$.

Comment: @Gödel Yes, i noticed that, but how from $ x_{n+1}-y_{n+1} $ occurs the right part of equality?

Comment: $x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}=\frac{(x_n+y_n)^2-4x_ny_n}{2(x_n+y_n)}=\frac{(x_n-y_n)^2}{2(x_n+y_n)}=\frac{x_n-y_n}{x_n+y_n}\cdot\frac{x_n-y_n}{2}$.

Comment: @Gödel I forgot to thank you !